# How can I rename an external drive in Nautilus file manager?

Tags: nautilus, usb-drive

I would like to be able to rename an external USB drive in Nautilus file manager.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Rename dialog pop-up]

Comment: Do you own the disk? Ie. is it set to your username?

Comment: I don't know. Shouldn't Ubuntu take care of this automatically so that I as a user can rename it by default?

Comment: You can rename it in command line, i have done it before, but I'm not aware of any GUI tools for that. Try Gnome Disks, they might have an option for that.

Comment: Use Gparted, unmount the drive, right-click the drive and choose `Label File System`.

Comment: Thank you for the alternatives! So why does Nautilus have this entry if it doesn't work?